# How can <H2> size be larger than the text, with no size set?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a border around an `<H2>` and the border is always rendered much larger than the `<h2>` text. No size is set anywhere.   The H2 contains one sentence of text with a 25px font size, and let Chrome Developer Tools -> Metrics reports that the size of the H2 is 980x183, and I can visibly see that this **extends beyond the text to the right, all the way up past the text to the top of the screen, and far, far to the left of the text.**

So, with no size being set, how can the area of the H2 element be so much larger than the text?  I might need to provide a lot more context for anyone to answer this, but it seems almost like the question should be able to stand alone.

The `<div>` containing the H2 is 0px x 0px, which also blows my mind a bit, but I've googled around quite a bit and don't feel that is likely to be related.

Comment: read about margin and padding

Comment: Try adding CSS: h2 { display: inline; padding:0;margin:0} h2 elements are displayed as blocks with default margin and padding

Comment: The H2 has 0 padding and 30px margin on only one size, such a small amount that I haven't paid it any attention.  I should have been clearer and mentioned that Chrome Dev Tools showed the size of the element as 980x183 not including margin or padding.  However, the display:inline totally did it; that totally makes the size of the H2 equals to its text.  I thought I had tried every combination of display/float/overflow for the H2 and most of its parent elements, but I guess not.  Thank you very much, @jtheman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding CSS:

```
 h2 { display: inline; padding:0;margin:0}
```

h2 elements are displayed as blocks with default margin and padding

Comment: I would expect a block element to take up more space to the right, but do you know how one could take up more space up and to the left?  Once again, I might not be providing enough context ...

Comment: @ardave yes that is the normal block behaviour if you"re having left aligned text i a standard H2 element. But there might be other conflicting CSS rules as for instance absolute positioned parent elements that puts the content out of "flow" etcetera. Yes you need to provide more info. Maybe add a jsfiddle showing your code example?

Comment: jsfiddle is completely new to me, but I'm going to spend some time learning it right now.

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` is a **block-level element**, which by default **stretches to the full width of its container**. That would mean that the width of the `h2` **box** and the `h2` **text** is not the same.

I'm not sure about your specific case, but you may want to change the `display` setting to either `inline` or `inline-block` and experiment with the results of those.

Comment: Mentally distinguishing the h2 box from the text will be useful to always consider.  Thanks!